# Negation of the statement all-and-greater that or equal

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I am proving something by contradiction. The conclusion is:

> All $a_{i}$'s and $b_{i}$'s are greater than or equal to zero.

I am finding it hard to negate this statement. Is the negation of this statement the following?

> Some $a_{i}$'s or $b_{i}$'s are less than or equal to zero.

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than "less than *or equal* to zero" it should be "*strictly less than* zero."  Remember that $x\geq 0$ and $x\leq 0$ are both simultaneously true when $x=0$.  Also, the phrasing "some $a_i$'s..." would to some people imply multiple, while we really want it to be just *at least one* $a_i$.

Comment: Rewritten:  The original statement is $\forall i~:~(a_i\geq 0)\wedge (b_i\geq 0)$.  The negation changes $\forall$ to $\exists$, changes $\wedge$ to $\vee$, changes $\geq$ to $<$ and so on, yielding the negation as $\exists i~\text{such that}~((a_i<0)\vee(b_i<0))$, there is some $i$ such that $a_i$ or $b_i$ is strictly less than zero.

Comment: @JMoravitz While I agree with what you're saying about "some" in daily speak, in mathematics (to me, at least)  it always means "at least one". However, that ought to be visible also in what verb conjugation you use. I could say "There _is_ some $a_i$ or $b_i$ which _is_ strictly less than $0$", rather than "are".